# How to skip global message handlers for a route?

Tags: asp.net

I've read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers and they mention that there is a way to add message handler per-route, but in the flow diagrams I can see that the message from MessageHandler3 still goes through the custom global MessageHandler1. How can I skip the global handler?

For example, I have 100 routes, on 99 of them I want to have the same message handler, so I register it as global, but on one of them, I want to have a different handler and I don't want the global one. Is it possible to avoid writing config.MapRoute(... 100 times to explicitly state the handlers for routes?

[image: Flow diagram]